# Help needed to transfer bird base to stretched bird base variant in John Szinger's origami fox model

Tags: paper, origami

I am stuck in step 7 to step 8 transition of the foxy fox model by John Szinger specified in the picture below.
Can somebody explain which folds are exactly being done to complete this transition?

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, take the bird base by the two flaps which are not folded, and pull them apart as far as you can without tearing the paper. The triangular part at the top of the bird base will flatten and stretch into a square. When you fold the model back flat, you will end up with the shape from step 8.

Comment: this helped a lot.

Comment: I need a video because I don't understand that but I do make origami.

Comment: See also: http://www.spitenet.com/origami/stretched.html for diagrams.